# iPhone App Installation

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, automation, active-directory

I am trying to develop an enterprise environment where the specified app in the app store gets installed in all the iOS devices connected to the company infrastructure, which has a windows based AD to verify the users. I went through various materials, and I found over the air profile delivery and few other methods like MDM to push the configuration. But it seems only the configuration can be pushed using these features.

In Apple Configurator and iPhone Configuration Utility, the devices should be connected to the computer physically. I would like to install the app in all the company-owened devices (around 1000 devices) without asking any permission from the user. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, installing apps 'without asking any permission' is definitely impossible. Attempting to install an enterprise app over the air will prompt upon attempted installation and the first attempted launch of the app. This is un-negotiable.

You can install apps over the air using enterprise distribution. This allows you to set up a 'portal'-like page which people can download the app from. A plist is downloaded to the device informing it of the location of the app bundle and some information about the app itself. For an example of this, see the [Stack Exchange iOS app beta](http://mobile.stackexchange.com/ios). For more information about enterprise distribution, see the guides available in the Member Centre.

Comment: Cool Answer! After connecting to MDM, there is a payload mechanism called Applock Payload, where the mobile gets locked to the app till the payload is removed. When apple provide such kind of mechanism, why even the admin could not able to completely automate the app installation?